# getting all info in session post and get

Tags: php

I want to display all the `session` , `post` , `get` information of my `php` page (`.php`) in the page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, everybody states the obvious, but they do not mention the security risk embedded in every solution.

I beg to differ, here is my alternative:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars(var_export($_POST, true), ENT_QUOTES);
echo htmlspecialchars(var_export($_GET, true), ENT_QUOTES);
echo htmlspecialchars(var_export($_SESSION, true), ENT_QUOTES);
echo "</pre>";
```

You probably do not think about an attacker putting malicious code into your session, but you never know.

To put it different:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
var_export($_POST);
var_export($_GET);
var_export($_SESSION);
```

will equally work well, but beware browsers trying to sniff the content.

Another method that prints two thirds of the stuff nicely:

```
phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);
```

And at last: Try the `<plaintext>` tag. It has no closing tag for obvious reasons, because it will end the interpretation of HTML in the browser, but after it was sent, you'll only have to care about printing plain text.

```
echo "<plaintext>";
var_export($_POST);
var_export($_GET);
var_export($_SESSION);
```

`var_export` has an advantage above `var_dump` and `print_r`: It prints valid PHP code that is able to recreate the variable. This is true 100% for any type but objects. Objects have to implement the magic static method `__set_state` to be able to be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to `print` / `var_dump` the information

For Session Is Below

```
<?php var_dump($_SESSION);  ?>
```

For Post Is Below

```
<?php var_dump($_POST);  ?>
```

For Get Is Below

```
<?php var_dump($_GET);  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION);  ?>

<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

<?php  print_r($_GET); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

### *POST*

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $postData = "POST Field " . htmlspecialchars($key) . " is " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>";
}
```

### *GET*

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $postData = "GET Field " . htmlspecialchars($key) . " is " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>";
}
```

### *SESSION*

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
  $postData = "SESSION Field " . htmlspecialchars($key) . " is " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer var_dump() over print_r(), as it handles objects as well.
I also like to output `<pre>` tags around my dump, so its easier to read in a browser, so

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```